# Distributing binary files

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm looking to distribute some binary files along with my Python project. Of course I need to provide one binary per supported architecture. So, I came with the following project structure:

```
/
├─ lib
│  ├─ any
│  │  └─ ...
│  ├─ x86_64
│  │  └─ ...
│  └─ <ARCH>
│     └─ ...
├─ myproj
└─ setup.py
```

I'd like to accomplish two things:

1. Merge the `lib` folders at build time so that if I have two file `/lib/any/file1` and `/lib/x86_64/file2`, I should end up when the project is deployed with `/lib/file1` and `/lib/file2`.
2. Be able to build a package by selecting the targeted architecture.

I've browsed the [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/) documentation but I don't think this usage is supported out of the box.

How to better distribute binary files (that are latter to be called using the `subprocess` module) along with a Python project?

Comment: I take it you can't make setup.py compile the binary/library file with the system it's installing against at `install` time?

Comment: I would install everything as a usual project file and in your code, switch at runtime depending on the current architecture. This would also make your code relocatable to different systems without requiring a new installation etc.